# Playing video with byte data PyQt6

Tags: pyqt6

I want to make a video player

in such a way that I convert the file into bytes and pass this byte to the media player

Actually, I want my media player to receive bytes instead of file address

but i get this error ->

```
setSource(self, QUrl): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QBuffer'
```

setSource does not take qbuffer value

how can i fix it?

code:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
from PyQt6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QMainWindow()
window.resize(500,500)
window.show()


player = QMediaPlayer()
file = open('Nino Rota- The Godfather.mp4' , 'rb')
file = file.read()
buffer = QBuffer()
buffer.open(QIODevice.OpenModeFlag.ReadWrite)

buffer.write(file)

player.setSource(buffer)

videoWidget = QVideoWidget(window)
videoWidget.setFixedSize(500,500)
player.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
videoWidget.show()

player.play()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: [`setSourceDevice()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediaplayer.html#setSourceDevice) is literally the *next* function after `setSource()` in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working properly now, but why am I getting this `QWindowsWindow::setDarkBorderToWindow: Unable to set dark window border.
Attempted to call isFormatSupported() without a window set`in the terminal?@musicamante

Comment: Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a forum (see the [tour]), comments should try to be inherent to the post subject.